# Копирование файлов PHP или Python?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, php

В общем, задача такая: пользователь отмечает галочками файлы, которые ему нужны, нажимает кнопочку и получает их для скачивания (в виде архива, к примеру). Думаю сделать так: на PHP генерируем текстовый файл-лист и передаем его на обработку скрипту на python, который и должен выполнить всю работу с файлами.
Скажите, это правильный подход?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, насколько это правильный подход, но я бы так навряд ли сделал, а уж если юзер чек-боксит файлы, то легче всего занести в бд или отдельный файл имена этих файлов, а потом уже лепить сборку по выбранным чек-боксам, пример сборки: [jquery ui download](http://jqueryui.com/download).

Comment: У него вопрос больше в том: перекинуть ли работу с файлами на python. 
А нагруженность большая? В целом можете делать все и на php. Если время будет - попробуйте сдублировать код на python  и сравнить скорость. По сути вам питон не обязателен. Точнее так: основным слабым местом будет архивация файлов. Вот ее и проверьте по скорости. К сожалению с питоном не работал, о скорости сказать не могу.

Comment: Файлы - они и так занесены в БД. По сути, когда пользователь выбирает файлы, PHP  обращается к БД и генерирует пути к ним.
Да, вопрос больше по нагрузке - я предполагаю, что будет вылетать по времени работы PHP. Нагрузка - за раз примерно 100-200 файлов. + к этому они копируются по сетевой Windows шаре с другого сервера. Кстати,  PHP умеет обращаться к Windows шаре с авторизацией?